# PHP libxml_get_errors() not working quite as I expected

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to use libxml_get_errors() to find any errors in an XML file.  It does show the first error encountered in the XML file.  However, I was expecting the results to contain an array entry for each error in the file.  Here is the code I am running:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = simplexml_load_file($file_name);
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
echo "<pre>" . print_r($errors,true) . "</pre>";
libxml_clear_errors();
```

But the only error that appears in the $error array is the first one encountered:

```
Array
(
[0] => LibXMLError Object
    (
        [level] => 3
        [code] => 9
        [column] => 34
        [message] => Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x99 0xA9 0x3C 0x2F
        [file] => orderexport_test2.xml
        [line] => 1216
    )

)
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Or should the libxml_get_errors() function return an array entry for EACH error in the XML file?

Comment: Are you sure you have other errors? https://3v4l.org/tqAFh

Comment: Yes, I manaully inserted the same invalid characters in another place in the file.  I also tried manually creating a mis-match tag.  In both cases, it is only returning the 1st error found.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that _Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding_ is so fatal that it can't/won't continue parsing.

Comment: The particular type of XML file I am processing is a list of orders.  So there is one main <orders> tag that encloses multiple child <order> tags.  With my initial testing, the 2 errors that I intentionally put into the file were both within the same <order> tag.  But, when I introduced another mis-matched tag in a totally separate <order> tag, I was able to get the libxml_get_orders() function to return 2 errors.  Will it not return multiple errors within the same begin & end tag?  My <order> tag is comprised of many child sub-elements.  And that is where I was intentionally putting errors.